# Is there an example where the maximal and maximum elements are different?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I know by heart the definitions of both maximal and maximum elements but cannot grasp examples when these dont coincide. Usually with numbers it is easy to see that maximum and maximal coincide. But what about when they dont coincide?

I recently read an example where we have three presidential (a,b and c) candidates and two groups that have preferences over them. So group one prefers a to b and b to c. Group 2 prefers b to a and a to c. As result they both rank c at the bottom. Thus a and b are maximum elements in society as a whole, which makes them both maximal and maximum elements.

Can you offer an example where we can have maximal elements and maximum elements in a set and that they dont coincide?

Finally, is it possible to have more than one element in the maximal set? My intuition says yes, but doesnt this make it coincide with maximal elements, as in the example of presidential candidates where both a and b are preferred to c?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the partially ordered set $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})-\{\Bbb{N}\}$ (ordered by inclusion relation $\subset$). It has maximal element. In fact, $\Bbb{N}-\{n\}$ is maximal elements of $\mathcal{P}(\Bbb{N})-\{\Bbb{N}\}$ so it has maximal elements infinitely many. But it does not have maximum.

You can easily check that every maximum is maximal element. If $(P,\le)$ is totally ordered then maximum and maximal element are coincide. (That is, every maximal element in totally ordered set is maximum in this set.)